# How to access a Windows share from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, windows, samba, file-sharing, smb

In Ubuntu 12.04 and previous versions, I can easily install `smbfs` and running `smb://server/share` from Nautilus works!

But, in 12.10, I can't install `smbfs`. Trying to install it from the terminal, I see this that the package is obsolete:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package smbfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  cifs-utils

E: Package 'smbfs' has no installation candidate
```

How can access my Windows share easily in 12.10?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it's replaced with `cifs-utils` now

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

There's also this nice and somewhat related [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) about mounting windows shares.

Answer (score 1):

If file is shared it will show under network folder. Samba client is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`Smb4K`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/smb4k/) or for command line [`smbclient`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smbclient/). Both can be installed through `Ubuntu Software Center`.